# Вставка элементов в список или массив по маске в Python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

Дано:

Битовая маска длины `N`, например

```
N = 8
mask = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

Сумма элементов в маске равна некоторому заданному `K`, в моем примере `К = 5`.

Дано двоичное сообщение длины `К`: `d = [1, 0, 1, 0, 0]`

Нужно из `d` получить вектор `u` используя маску. Вместо единиц в маске вставляются биты из `d`. В моем примере `u = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]`

На python 3 получилась вот такая функция:

```
def precode(info, mask):
    precoded = mask[:]
    j = 0
    for i in range(len(mask)):
        if precoded[i] == 1:
            precoded[i] = info[j]
            j += 1
    return precoded
```

В MATLAB та же операция выглядит следующим образом:

```
u = zeros(N, 1);
u(mask == 1) = d; %непосредственно вставка бит
```

Насколько я знаю, выполняется такая операция быстрее, чем перебор поэлементно в цикле. Есть ли что-то подобное матлабовской операции в python (например, в numpy)?

Comment: при подходящих типах: `u[mask] = d`

Comment: С numpy будет практически также выглядеть: u = np.zeros(N, dtype=np.int8); u[mask] = d.astype(np.int8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример с использованием Numpy:

```
In [61]: import numpy as np

In [62]: N = 8

In [63]: mask = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1])

In [64]: d = [1, 0, 1, 0, 0]

In [65]: u = np.zeros(N, dtype=np.int8)

In [66]: u[mask == 1] = d

In [67]: u
Out[67]: array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], dtype=int8)
```

Comment: вам не кажется или что  функция автора делает не то?

Comment: @VasylKolomiets, если выполнить `precode(d, mask)`, то результат будет правильным...